# Send mail function adds mail logs into response

Tags: php, httpresponse, swiftmailer

When I'm trying to send email with SwiftMailer it's working ok, but in response I'm getting additional html logs like this:

```
{"status":"ok"}++ Starting Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport<br />
&lt;&lt; 220-s206.avahost.net ESMTP Exim 4.86 #2 Fri, 20 Nov 2015 16:42:03 +0200 
220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 
220 and/or bulk e-mail.
<br />
&gt;&gt; EHLO znaidusvoe.com
<br />
&lt;&lt; 250-s206.avahost.net Hello s206.avahost.net [77.120.110.175]
250-SIZE 52428800
250-8BITMIME
250-PIPELINING
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
250-STARTTLS
250 HELP
<br />
&gt;&gt; AUTH LOGIN
<br />
&lt;&lt; 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
<br />
&gt;&gt; c3VwcG9ydEB6bmFpZHVzdm9lLmNvbQ==
<br />
&lt;&lt; 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
<br />
&gt;&gt; YWRtaW4xcTJ3M2U0cjV0
<br />
&lt;&lt; 235 Authentication succeeded
<br />
++ Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport started<br />
&gt;&gt; MAIL FROM:&lt;support@znaidusvoe.com&gt;
<br />
&lt;&lt; 250 OK
<br />
&gt;&gt; RCPT TO:&lt;vladislav.kosko@gmail.com&gt;
<br />
&lt;&lt; 250 Accepted
<br />
&gt;&gt; DATA
<br />
&lt;&lt; 354 Enter message, ending with &quot;.&quot; on a line by itself
<br />
&gt;&gt; 
.
<br />
&lt;&lt; 250 OK id=1Zzmt1-002Hws-Op
<br />
++ Stopping Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport<br />
&gt;&gt; QUIT
<br />
&lt;&lt; 221 s206.avahost.net closing connection
<br />
++ Swift_Transport_EsmtpTransport stopped<br />
```

This happens on shared hosting but on my local machine all ok.

How I can disable this logs? 
I need to get only `{"status":"ok"}`

Comment: Shorten the log output and post your code; this looks like the `Swift_Plugins_LoggerPlugin` is active.

Comment: You're right. Thank you.